# Ubuntu: Cannot disable Wayland on multiple users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teamviewer, gdm, wayland

I am attempting to disable Wayland on 2 users at the same time on my machine so I could remote connect using TeamViewer.

I tried setting `$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` to `WaylandEnable=false` on both users, but whenever I use `$ sudo systemctl restart gdm3` on user 1, then Wayland is re-enabled on user 2, vice versa.

I want to permanently disable Wayland globally on both users, is there something I am missing out on?

Ubuntu Version: 22.04.1 LTS